# R (funtion-loop) Looping with a function(another loop with a list) and assigning a value to a dataframe with the right keyword from the funciton loop

Tags: r, function, loops

I'm new to R and trying to write a Script to assign Product Categories to a list of Product Titles. I have a lookup table which has associates the keywords corresponding to a particular Product Categeory.
eg.

```
mouse <- c("mouse","keyboard")
laptop <- c("laptop","notebook","thinkpads")
tv <- c("tv","television")
```

I have combined this in a list as

```
lookups <- list(mouse,laptop,tv)
```

My NAs dataset looks like this :

```
NAs <- read.csv(somefile.csv)

brand   product_title           category
Asus    Asus Zenphone 2 ZE551ML other
Beko    Frost Free Combi Fridge other
Beko    Frost Free Combi Fridge other
Beko    EcoSmart American Style other
Beko    Cookmaster              other
```

What i want is to do a search in the product_title and assign a category based on my lookup list.
So far I have written a function to do a search based on the list:

```
assigncategory <- function(product_title) {
    for(j in 1:length(lookups)){
     if (length(grep(paste(lookups[j], collapse="|"),product_title,value=T,ignore.case=T))>0){
    return (colnames(lookups[j])
   } else {
    return ("Other")
  }
  }
}
```

---

And now i loop this function to assign the right category to my dataset:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(NAs)) {
  if(NAs$category[i]=="Other"){
  NAs$category[i] <- assigncategory(NAs[i,"product_title"])
  } else {
  NAs$category[i] <- NAs$category[i]
}
}
table(NAs$category)
```

The result still gives me this and doesn't assign any category to any of my products.

```
> table(NAs$category)
Other 
 2510
```

Please help me in understanding what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: None of the `product_title` values in the sample you provided have any of those keywords; is that the case for all observations?

Comment: I have 2510 rows of product_title and many of them has the keywords. The list i shown here is just a subset of my keywords.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
assigncategory <- function(product_title) {
  for(j in 1:length(lookups)){
    if (length(grep(paste(lookups[j], collapse="|"),product_title,value=T,ignore.case=T))>0){
      return (colnames(lookups[j])
   } else {
     return ("Other")
   }
  }
}
```

This loop checks the first vector within `lookups`, and if it finds the item it returns `NULL`, since `colnames` of a vector will always be NULL. If it doesn't find the item, it returns "Other" **without checking any of the other members of `lookups`**.

Here's a corrected version:

```
assigncategory <- function(product_title) {
  for(j in 1:length(lookups)){
    if (grepl(paste(lookups[[j]], collapse="|"),product_title,ignore.case=TRUE)){
      return (names(lookups)[j])
    }
  }
  return("Other")
}
```

You also need to ensure your list is named:

```
lookups <- list(mouse = mouse, laptop = laptop, tv = tv)
```

Comment: Thanks Nick for the input but unfortunately it still gives me the same result (only Others). I tried a _names(lookups)_ and it returns **NULL**. I have been searching online and could not find how to return the column name of a a list. I have also tried changing the list lookup to a dataframe and still no luck.

Comment: @DanielNingthemcha hadn't picked up that your list wasn't named. See edit above.

Comment: unfortunately it still doesn't work. I have even tried changing some of the keywords in my lookups list to ensure I use those words which matches the product_titles. Still all my categories are assigned Others.

Comment: I was missing some square brackets. It should have been `lookups[[j]]` not `lookups[j]`. Try it now

Comment: Thanks a lot Nick. This definitely worked. You've made my day :)

Comment: Hi @NickKennedy. I'm trying to use a lookup spreadsheet rather than a manual list **(lookup)** for my keyword search. What i have is a spreadsheet named **Key** which has columns as: **Column A**: _Soundbar,sound bar, soundplate_ **Column B**: _Washing Machine, lavadora,washer,washmachine_ **Column C** _Covers,case_. What i want to do is search each column and return the first word for my category. Could you please help how to do this as my approach is not working.

Comment: @DanielNingthemcha I think it might be better posting this as a new question rather than a comment to one from over 2 months ago. That would also give you the opportunity of detailing your approach to date. The data you've detailed is probably still best represented as a list or as a `data.frame` with two columns but I would mention in your question how your input data is actually formatted. CSV? Excel? Something else?

Comment: I hjave posted the question at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33395486/assigning-names-to-each-row-based-on-a-word-match-from-a-lookup-spreadsheet-in-r  . Please help me out. Many thanks.